# How could I get acceptable precision when converting a float to int gives an erroneous result?

Tags: c, type-conversion

I'm currently running through a strange case :
I have a double value with one decimal, ie. 24.9

from this value I want to get the entire part ie. entire = 24
and, aside, the decimal part in the form : decimal = 9

to do this I proceed as follows

```
double temp_double = 24.9;
double entire;
double decimal = modf(temp_double, &entire)*10;
```

which gives :

```
>printf("entire part = %f\n", entire);
>printf("decimal part = %f\n", decimal);

entire part = 24.000000
decimal part = 9.000000
```

Then for further processing I need to convert it into integer, so I do

```
entire = (int)entire;
decimal = (int)decimal;
```

and then, if I print it, it gives me :

```
entire part = 24
decimal part = 8  ==> erroneous value
```

with 24.7 I encounter a similar problem (get 6 instead of 7).

I know this is a rounding issue and I would like to know if there is any way I can improve my code in order to temper those issues. I mean is there any extra computing (use a different scale, a different base, whatever ...) that I could apply in order to, finally, get the correct value for the decimal part ?

otherwise, many values may not be properly reported

any help appreciated ... :(

Comment: Use the `round()` function: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/round

Comment: How would you handle an input of `24.86`?  If that's not valid and you only have inputs up to one decimal place, you shouldn't be using floating-point numbers - you should be using something like `int` but scaled by a factor of 10.

Comment: well, actually that's what I realized, and I'll do so ... I was dividing for convenience until I met the problem but I can cope with the factor of 10. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well finally I'll use a factor of ten as it will be easy to handle in the further processings.
I should have read comments quicker, it would have saved me some time.
Thanks @AndrewHenle and @AdrianMole for your help

Comment: serious question, why donb't you use the round() function? As a challenge? Or just, because you don't want to use it?

Comment: Well, initially my data is a temperature data that I recover from a frame and it is expressed in tenth of degrees. I prefer to use a factor of 10 as it is just ... doing nothing. At the time I really need to use the decimal value I just do "value%10" to get the decimal part.